# Share a File from Android to PC (windows)

Tags: android, share

I’m new to android´s app development; so far I was able to create text files on my device. The problem is when I try move the file to my PC I cannot find it. After research I now know that files saved in the internal memory are only available to the app and the external storage can be use to share files, but my device (moto G 1° gen) only have internal memory.
So the question is, is there a way to share files on my smartphone with my pc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, devices with internal memory still have a partition set aside that emulates external storage.  On any Android device I've had, the internal memory is mounted to /sdcard/ and if you insert an actual sdcard, it gets mounted to /sdcard2/.  Anything you save in /sdcard/ should appear in Windows explorer when plugging the device in over USB.

Alternatively, you can also use adb to retrieve files outside of the /sdcard/ partition by using the command "adb.exe pull [source file] [destination directory(optional)]"